# Exception when calling DataTable.Select() with NULLIF

Tags: c#, ado.net

I get the following error

"The expression contains undefined function call NULLIF()"

when calling DataTable.Select() like this

```
DataTable.Select("(((NULLIF([Field].[EU], '') IS NULL) OR ([Field].[EU] IS NULL) )))");
```

I have no problem running this by hand in the sql manager console, or does the C# Select interface not have access to all sql functions?

Comment: Why do you need to ask us "does the C# Select interface not have access to all sql functions"?  Why haven't you read the documentation for that method?  That would tell you exactly what it supports.  If you haven't used the Help menu in VS then you shouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write it like this:

```
DataTable.Select("[Field].[EU]='' OR [Field].[EU] IS NULL");
```

I don't understand why you are making your life harder. Your statement is not readable and really hard to understand!